# Why won't my picture appear in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm starting out with ReactJS & I want this simple image to appear on my practice web app but it isn't appearing.  I thought my logic was correct but I guess not.

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <title>My website</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="firstBar"></div>
    <div id="body"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="body.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's my `body.js` file:

```
import myPic from 'pictures/myPic.JPG' // myPic.JPG is in my pictures folder.

var Body = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <img src={myPic}></img>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Body />, document.getElementById('body'));
```

Error I'm getting is:

```
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at eval (eval at transform.run (browser.js:4613), <anonymous>:6:25)
at Function.transform.run (browser.js:4613)
at exec (browser.js:4649)
at browser.js:4661
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (browser.js:4632)`
```

Comment: Are there any errors being thrown or is the image just not showing?

Comment: @KeithA yep, I'll include it in my post right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

require/import might not be supported in the browser
Try this:

```
var Body = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
 return(
  <img src={"./pictures/myPic.JPG"}></img>
);
}
});
ReactDOM.render(<Body />, document.getElementById('body'));
```

Comment: If it's just a string literal there's no need to wrap in curly braces.

Comment: @chompy Because you are importing, which is being transformed by Babel into ES5. Once it's been transpiled, it uses `require` but `require` isn't defined in the browser, it's provided by module libraries such as RequireJS. If you don't use a packager like browserify or webpack to bundle it for the browser, modules won't work as they aren't implemented (yet).